# Storing and using requests responses in python 3

Tags: json, python-3.x, python-requests

I'm making n number of API calls using the requests library and I need to save the responses for each call and use them later as a parameter in another call.  The following is the code I'm using to make the calls and what I've tried:

```
for i in range(n):
        r = requests.post(url, headers=headers, data=data)
        print(r.json())
```

The response I recieve and what is printed is:

```
{"SUBID": "7425722"}
```

How could I save possibly a list of these, or a dictionary of them, and use them as parameters again in another loop of n iterations? For example:

```
for i in range(n):
    data = r[n]
    requests.post(url, headers=headers, data=data)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
second_urls = []

for i in range(n):
     r = requests.post(url, headers=headers, data=data)
     second_urls.append(r.json())

# then loop over the second list:
for j in second_urls:
     url = j 
     requests.post(url, headers=headers, data=data)
```

For a little better performance (maybe a lot better if you dont care about the order of the response) you could use [grequests](https://github.com/kennethreitz/grequests).

Comment: where was second_list and make_url created?

Comment: `second_list` was a typo and`make_url` is just for the example, sorry if it confused you.

Comment: wouldn't it just be url = j?

Comment: Edited ..I removed the other bits as they weren't necessary.